# Updated select list with another - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I'm attempting to handle two select lists, such that the sum of their computed values is equal to some max size. i.e., if the maximum number of people is 20, and 5 children are selected - a maximum of 15 adults can be added, and so on.

My last attempt:

template:

```
<div class="form-row">
 <div class="col">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="adultNumber">How many adults are in your party?</label>
     <select class="form-control form-control-sm" v-model.lazy="adultNumber" v-on:change="updateChildPartySizes" id="adultNumberVal">
       <option v-for="n in maxAdultPartyArray">[[ n ]]</option>
     </select>
     Answer : [[ adultNumber ]]
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="childNumber">How many children are in your party?</label>
     <select class="form-control form-control-sm" v-model.lazy="childNumber" v-on:change="updateAdultPartySizes" id="childNumberVal">
       <option v-for="n in maxChildPartyArray">[[ n ]]</option>
     </select>
     Answer : [[ childNumber ]]
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Vue instance:

```
<script>
    let app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        bookingDetails: true,
        yourDetails: false,
        sessionName: null,
        specialRequests: '',
        adultNumber: 0,
        childNumber: 0,
        maxAdultPartySize: 20,
        maxChildPartySize: 20,
        maxAdultPartyArray: Array.apply(null, {length: 20 + 1}).map(Number.call, Number),
        maxChildPartyArray: Array.apply(null, {length: 20 + 1}).map(Number.call, Number),
        sessionSize: {{ sessionSize }},
        csrfToken : '{{ csrf_token }}',
      },
      delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
      methods: {
        updateChildPartySizes: function (adultNumber) {
          this.maxChildPartySize = this.maxChildPartyArray.length - adultNumber;
          this.maxChildPartyArray = Array.apply(null, {length: this.maxChildPartySize}).map(Number.call, Number);
        },
        updateAdultPartySizes: function (childNumber) {
          this.maxAdultPartySize = this.maxAdultPartyArray.length - childNumber;
          this.maxAdultPartyArray = Array.apply(null, {length: this.maxAdultPartySize}).map(Number.call, Number);
        },
      }
    });
</script>
```

I've tried a number of things, but not a lot seems to be work. As far as I can see, the Maths and array manipulation is correct ... just not the final desired output...

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is assuming the eventhandler called from onChange will get the model value passed in. It actually gets a HTMLElement change-event. So just don't use that and use the model directly - which is updated automatically.

```
updateChildPartySizes: function () {
    this.maxChildPartySize = this.maxChildPartyArray.length - this.adultNumber;
```

I found this by first trying:

```
console.log(this.maxChildPartySize); // NaN
```

And since NaN is infectious like the plague we know that one of the two variables added together must be bad, so I logged those and and found a the event.

Also keep in mind that models (`v-model="something"`) are two-way bindings by definition, meaning it binds `:selected="foo"` (one way) and `v-on:change="foo"` under the hood.

Comment: I have just tried this with a slight tweak - and has worked. I don't know if I missed something because I had this at some point. Makes sense to update from this.adultNumber directly! Thank you so much.